# mysqli real escape string issues

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I use `mysqli_real_escape_string` in my script to prevent SQL injection. I was working on some code and asking some questions here and I was advised to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`, the problem is my code does not make a connection until after the variables I want to secure. It was suggested that I should used prepared statements instead but after some searching http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php I feel more confused. Right now the code if doing exactly what it is not supposed to do, it is inserting empty values/rows into my table, which from my reading is probably because of the use of `mysqli_real_escaape_string`

Any thoughts or help is appreciated, I am so frustrated and confused but still trying to learn. Here is the code:

```
<?php
//Form fields passed to variables
$manu = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputManu']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputModel']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputDesc']);

//Connect to database using $conn
include ('connection.php');

//Insert record into table 
$sql = "INSERT INTO gear (`id`,`manu`,`model`,`desc`)
      VALUES (NULL,'$manu','$model','$desc')";

//Check for empty fields
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{   
   foreach($_POST as $val) 
    {
      if(trim($val) == '' || empty($val))
       {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
       echo "Please complete all form fields!";
       echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../add.php'>"; 
       }
    }

     if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
     {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
     }
     else
     {
       //echo "1 record added";
         echo "Success, You added the ".$manu." ".$model."";
         echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../index.php'>";
     }   
}
else
{
echo "some error";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
//Connect to database using $conn
include ('connection.php');

//Form fields passed to variables
$manu  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['inputManu']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['inputModel']);
$desc  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['inputDesc']);
```

Comment: That makes sense and I see the difference in usage from the old mysql usage. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope Below code will help you.

```
<?php
    //Connect to database using $conn
    /*in connection.php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    */
    include ('connection.php');


    //Check for empty fields
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {  
            //Form fields passed to variables
    $manu = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['inputManu']);
    $model = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['inputModel']);
    $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['inputDesc']);


    if($manu!='' && $model!="" && $desc!="")
    {

    //Insert record into table 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO gear (`id`,`manu`,`model`,`desc`)
          VALUES (NULL,'$manu','$model','$desc')";
        $r=mysqli_query($link,$sql) ; 
           //echo "1 record added";
           if($r)
           {       
             echo "Success, You added the ".$manu." ".$model."";
            // echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../index.php'>";
            } 
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Please complete all form fields!";
         }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Ok, well what is the main advantage of this method compared to the above method? I am just looking to see how this is different, thanks,

Comment: earlier i think ur using two page for doing this task one with html and other with php.in my code i have used only one page for this task.do every think after form submit. that all.